# The descriptions of pyramids in Vedic scriptures

Tags: vedas, puranas, temple, vastu-shastra

Do Vedas (and any other Vedic scripture, such as Puranas) hold any information on pyramids? What is their function? What can they do?

Comment: How is it an off-topic question? OP clearly asking about pyramids in Hindu scriptures.

Answer (score 1):

A Pyramid will have 5 faces.

[image]

---

The Vedic literature contains many hymns, describing spiritual aspects, in esoteric fashion.  So if we consider those esoteric mentions, we can infer that a Pyramid is a an symbolic representation of [panchabhutas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pancha_Bhoota) or 5 elements.

1. Agni - Fire
2. Vayu/Indra - Air
3. Varuna   - water
4. Earth   - Aditi
5. Space/Heaven   - Tvastr

---

Earth and Heaven are called the Parents of Gods in [Rig Veda I.185.4](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv01185.htm)

> May we be close to both the Worlds who suffer no pain, **Parents of
>   Gods**, who aid with favour, Both mid the Gods, with Day and Night
>   alternate. Protect us, Heaven and Earth, from fearful danger.

---

The 5 faces of a pyramid represent 5 elements of Nature/God.  That is why even the temple domes resemble, though not in exact manner, a pyramid.

[image]

The Meru Sri Yantra also resembles a pyramid.

[image]

---

Even a human sitting in a cross-legged fashion or in padmAsana, resembles a pyramid.

[image]

---

So pyramid is every where and in all times, only difference being in Egypt, the structures were constructed in exact pyramid shape.

Comment: These are only similar shapes of Pyramids but is there anything specifically about pyramids itself? Their effects, uses etc., I ask this because people who are advocating pyramids are not suggesting Meru Sri Yantra or gopuram. They are suggesting an exact replica of pyramidal shape while meditation.

Comment: Based on my research of Vastu-sastra (derived from hindu websites), pyramids provide an overall positive effect on human beings. They somehow focus energies. However, I couldn't find any infomration from original Vedic sources. I wonder if Vastu-sastra has any information.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma: has it been proven that if one meditates under pyramid shaped structure, advancement in spirituality is guaranteed?  I don't think so.  If that was the case did Sri Ramakrishna or Sri Ramana Maharshi or for that Buddha meditate under pyramid shaped structure?

Comment: @MarinoKlisovich: Personal experiences may be different.  You mght have experienced such positive effect out of your own advancement in spirituality. We cannot generalise.